# Correct loading order javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, loading

What is the correct loading order javascript script in a HTML file if was using cordova and jqm?

I have this sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllerCordova.js"></script>  
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use order like this

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllerCordova.js"></script>  
<script src="js/javascript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For posterity's sake, I fix the only answer. The JQuery Mobile must be loaded after the custom script because the `mobileinit` event is triggered as soon as the JQuery Mobile script is loaded.

Reference : http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

On the contrary, it seems (I'm not sure) that Cordova must be loaded at the beginning. When it is loaded at the end of the page, the `pause/resume` events are not triggered.

Indeed, the `deviceready`'s Cordova event is special in that, any event handler registered after the `deviceready` event fires has its callback function called immediately.

Reference : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html